# Why are plasmas able exist over such a wide range of temperatures and densities?

Tags: plasma-physics

Does it have to do with the long-range nature of the Coulomb interaction?

Comment: I think you are looking for Debye shielding effects that inhibit any forces that would act to recombine the opposite charge constituents.

Comment: Please provide some context for your question, and indicate what research you have done already to find an answer.

Comment: sammy gerbil, Unfortunately, the body of my research is much more than I can fit into 550 characters or less ... I was hoping to generate a discussion, to get around the apparent character limit.

Comment: @anoegenetic, then I would suggest including a summary of your research.

Comment: @anoegenetic as far as I'm aware, there is no character limit on questions. You can still include your research. Furthermore, this is a Q&A site, not a discussion forum. Ask a question, we'll try to answer. Try to generate a discussion, you'll likely get closed as too broad

Answer (score 1):

Plasma is generally formed by the excitation of electrons in the atoms.They are usually mixtures of ionized gases and free electrons. They exist in wide ranges of temparature and densities because different substances require different amount of energies(Ionization Potentials) to have themselves ionized or to get their electrons excited.

Comment: The definition of a plasma is more complicated than just a collection of ionized gases and free electrons. For example, in order to be considered a (ideal) plasma, the condition that there be more than 1 charge carrier per Debye sphere must be satisfied, which is necessary for collective behavior. My question is more along the lines of whether the ability for plasmas to exist over such a broad range in parameter space depend on the long-range nature of the Coulomb interaction (which is what gives rise to this collective behavior).

Answer (score 1):

Only indirectly.

Plasma exist if the mean kinetic energy of the electrons is too high to form a bound state with the nuclei. In the case of the hydrogene, it is over 13.6eV.

Thus, for $0 < E < 13.6\mathrm{eV}$, we have non-plasma (solid, fluid gaseous) hydrogene.

For $13.6\mathrm{eV} < E < \infty$, we have plasma.

The second interval is obviously much bigger. :-)

In atoms with more protons, it is higher, but not much.

Thus, it doesn't depend on the range of the EM interaction, it depends on the binding energies.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to respond, peterh. I understand quite well the ionization mechanism. However, a plasma is more than just an ionized gas. It must also exhibit collective behavior, among other things.  For example, in order to be considered a (ideal) plasma, the condition that there be more than 1 charge carrier per Debye sphere must be satisfied, which is necessary for collective behavior. My question is: does the long-range nature of the Coulomb interaction allow for plasmas that exist under very different conditions to exhibit the same behavior?

Comment: Plasmas composed of electrons and protons (i.e., the constituents of atomic hydrogen) can exist with temperatures less than 13.6 eV.  The solar wind, for instance, generally has electron temperatures between ~5-10 eV.

Comment: @honeste_vivere Thanks! I suspect it is because they are not very dense. If they would have enough time for it, I think they would recombine.

Comment: @anoegenetic Sorry, I can understand your question but in this case it depends on what we define "plasma" and "wide range". For example, a white dwarf is far enough hot as the around 10000K required to the plasma state, despite that I wouldn't call its state plasma. Unfortunately, I think it is mainly a terminologic thing. There are state equations of the matter, (theoretically) they result plasma-like behavior (conductivity, etc) in a part of their parameter spaces, it depends on how we define the "wide range". I am sorry that I can't say more.

Comment: @peterh - Not necessarily, a plasma is considered a quasi-neutral, non-equilibrium gas that exhibits a collective behavior.  I think the more important parameter would be the Coulomb collision rate relative to the local plasma frequency, but I don't recall off hand (we never worry about recombination because the rates are so low as to be negligible in all the plasmas I work with)...